# Web browser hosting issue in asp.net mvc applicaton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-scraping

In my Asp.Net MVC web application I have to fetch data from a site through website. For scraping data I need to login to the site and then reach to a site via clicking a menu tab and then from that page I need to scrape the data. The site to the scraped contains 2 Frames. I had previously implemented web scraping in one of my windows project by windows web browser control.

I followed the following [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET) to integrate web browser control on to my web application. Everything worked fine under visual studio environment and I get my data from scraping the site via web browser. But when I tried to host the application, it doesn’t worked as expected. The web browser control doesn’t get loaded. I searched for the solution but couldn’t get a feasible solution yet. I have tried to implement the same via iframe and also by using Silverlight Webbrowser control and by using javascript to ivoke the login events, but it too get failed due to access denial because of cross domain issue.

So is there any way to scrape data by logging to the site in asp.net web application. Can I make my windows application as an ActiveX control and use it. Will ActiveX has cross browser issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered just fetching the desired content using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` or `System.Net.WebRequest`?

Comment: Yes, yes i tried using the same but it failed. i suspect because the site to be scrapped contains multiple frames?

Comment: Is there a possibility that you can just make a separate application that handles the scraping? And then you save the results in either a database or a textfile, that your website can read from.

Comment: My guess is that Windows Server security restrictions are preventing IIS from firing up the browser, or preventing the browser from operating properly.  How can you tell that the browser control is not being loaded?

Comment: You do not need browser control to do the scraping. Use System.Net.WebRequest. When you get the framed page, parse it to get the URL for each frame. Then get the frame you are interested in. Or go straight to that frame if the URL is known.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the approach of using a web browser seems heavy and will be subject to other environmental restrictions. Your best approach is to create a separate, testable repository to scrape data - either on-demand or with a spider approach in advance if you really need to (and the target data doesn't change).

Yes, different browsers will have problems with it if you try to make it ActiveX. Security may not allow it. There are really many factors here; if your environment isn't controlled, this is not a great option.

Assuming you'd go with an on-demand approach, I would highly suggest creating a webservice or class you can reference. You could then use an open-source parser server-side, such as:

1. [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) if the document isn't well-formed, or,
2. [Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) if you can trust the document integrity.

Basically, you'll need to authenticate, store your authentication cookie and finally load the target document via a second request populated with your authentication cookie. Feed *that* page into your parser (CsQuery or Fizzler).

An example of performing the login would be as follows:

```
private HttpWebRequest PerformLoginRequest(CookieContainer container)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(YOUR_POST_URL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.CookieContainer = container;

    _logger.DebugFormat("Attempting login for '{0}'", _username);
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    // assumes the un/pw is stored in a field
    var credentials = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", _username, _password);
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(credentials);

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        try
        {
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error in login attempt.", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

The cookies container that comes back will have a set-cookie that you'll need to parse out so that subsequent requests have the authentication bits properly presented. I had to do this, and worked off of code I found somewhere here on SO but can't find the reference now.  It may look something like this (explanation here [Set-Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
private static CookieContainer ProcessCookieContainer(HttpWebRequest request, CookieContainer container)
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    var cookierReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string htmldoc = cookierReader.ReadToEnd();

    var cookieHeader = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
    response.Close();

    container = new CookieContainer();
    foreach (var cookie in cookieHeader.Split(','))
    {
        // these are ; seperated name/value pairs
        var split = cookie.Split(';');
        string name = split[0].Split('=')[0];
        string value = split[0].Split('=')[1];

        // create the cookie with the domain
        var c = new Cookie(name, value) {Domain = "YourCookieDomain.com"};

        container.Add(c);
    }
    return container;
}
```

And to load a doc to parse it you might do something like:

```
public string GetValueFromSomePage(int first, string second)
{
    var container = new CookieContainer();

    // do login
    var request = PerformLoginRequest(container);

    // chew on cookies
    container = ProcessCookieContainer(request, container);

    var result = string.Empty;
    var requestUrl = string.Format("http://YourUrlWithParams.com/?first={0}&second={1}", 123, "abc");
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    request.CookieContainer = container;

    using (var serverResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(serverResponse.GetResponseStream());
            var responseDoc = new CQ(reader);

            // do something with CSS selectors...
            result = responseDoc["input[name=name]"].FirstElement().Value;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error fetching data.", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            serverResponse.Close();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I hope this helps. There are a few moving parts here, but you likely expect that already given the nature of your task.

Cheers.